# Upgrade to react-navigation 6 --> Found screens with the same name nested inside one another

Tags: react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation 6`
I create a **HomeStack** :
`const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator()`
I create **HomeNavigator**:

```
const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name={ScreenTypes.Home} component={HomeScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
```

I create another **RootNavigator** with include **HomeNavigator**:

```
const RootNavigator = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      animation: 'fade',
    }}
  >
    <RootStack.Screen name={ScreenTypes.Home} component={HomeNavigator} />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
)
```

When I run app, I got following warning issue

```
Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check:

Home, Home > Home

This can cause confusing behavior during navigation. Consider using unique names for each screen instead.
```

I not sure what need to do